# ...mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p247

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I'm using windows7x64, ruby2.0.0p247, rails4.0.0 and mysql5.5.27.
When I run the `$ rails server` command, I got the following error.

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.13/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27) [x64-mingw32]
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: I'm getting this too. I don't suppose you found a solution? I have tried 32-bit and 64-bit and both fail with similar kinds of error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libmysql.lib included in the MySQL Connector/C 64 bit is not compatible with the mingw64-gcc compiler.

You need to generate mingw64 compatible libmysql.lib file.

To generate libmysql.lib file, you need gendef.exe, which can obtain from mingw-w64 distribution(I got from https://code.google.com/p/structure-svm-map/downloads/detail?name=svm-map-win.zip&can=2&q=)

In the lib folder of the mysql connector, produce libmysql.lib with the following steps.

gendef.exe libmysql.dll

dlltool -v --dllname libmysql.dll --def libmysql.def --output-lib libmysql.lib

And running the normal gem install command. gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.12b6' -- --with-opt-dir="..."

NOTE: In case of MySQL Connector/C 6.1, due to the version comparison routine, you cannot use mysql2 module with the following exception. RuntimeError: Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.7.2-m12 but the client library is 6.1.0.

You should use mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-winx64.msi in http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads

Source: https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/8591