# Unable to start Webrick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick, mysql2

I'm following the tutorial from lynda.com and I'm trying to start the Webrick server.
I'm on Windows 8, I had some trouble installing the mysql2 gem.

This is the output when i type 'rails server'

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.0.0/mysql2-0.3.14/mysql2/mysql2.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22) [x64-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0018 p:-9412162 s:0062 e:000061 TOP    [FINISH]
c:0017 p:---- s:0060 e:000059 CFUNC  :require
c:0016 p:0083 s:0056 e:000055 TOP    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8 [FINISH]
c:0015 p:---- s:0054 e:000053 CFUNC  :require
c:0014 p:0037 s:0050 e:000049 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0047 e:000046 CFUNC  :each
c:0012 p:0055 s:0044 e:000043 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72 [FINISH]
c:0011 p:---- s:0037 e:000036 CFUNC  :each
c:0010 p:0030 s:0034 e:000033 METHOD C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61
c:0009 p:0013 s:0030 e:000029 METHOD C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131
c:0008 p:0049 s:0026 e:000025 TOP    C:/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0007 p:---- s:0024 e:000023 CFUNC  :require
c:0006 p:0014 s:0020 e:000019 BLOCK  C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74 [FINISH]
c:0005 p:---- s:0017 e:000016 CFUNC  :tap
c:0004 p:0562 s:0014 e:000013 TOP    C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0008 e:000007 CFUNC  :require
c:0002 p:0034 s:0004 E:001118 EVAL   bin/rails:4 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 E:0017f8 TOP    [FINISH]

bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
C:/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb:131:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2.rb:8:in `require'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(ZwWaitForSingleObject+0xa) [0x00007FFAF8DF65BA]
C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x98) [0x00007FFAF6391148]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0x9d) [0x000000006F28601D]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x838) [0x000000006F141F98]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_bug+0x45) [0x000000006F142D45]
C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\x64-msvcrt-ruby200.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x18c) [0x000000006F20AEAC]
 [0x0000000000401A85]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_C_specific_handler+0x87) [0x00007FFAF8DE831F]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(_chkstk+0x9d) [0x00007FFAF8DF921D]
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll(RtlAppendUnicodeToString+0x3ab) [0x00007FFAF8DB5B5B]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: bin/rails

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
    2 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    3 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
    4 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
    5 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/compatibility.rb
    6 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults.rb
    7 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    8 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/errors.rb
    9 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/version.rb
   10 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/requirement.rb
   11 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/platform.rb
   12 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
   13 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
   14 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/util/stringio.rb
   15 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb
   16 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb
   17 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
   18 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/utf_16le.so
   19 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
   20 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
   21 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/thread.rb
   22 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb
   23 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
   24 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb
   25 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/enc/trans/single_byte.so
   26 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/path_support.rb
   27 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb
   28 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/pathname.so
   29 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/pathname.rb
   30 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/constants.rb
   31 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/io/console.so
   32 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/user_interaction.rb
   33 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/etc.so
   34 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/config_file.rb
   35 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb
   36 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/current_ruby.rb
   37 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb
   38 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb
   39 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/gem_path_manipulation.rb
   40 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/gem_helpers.rb
   41 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/match_platform.rb
   42 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_ext.rb
   43 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/version.rb
   44 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler.rb
   45 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/settings.rb
   46 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/digest.so
   47 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/digest.rb
   48 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/digest/sha1.so
   49 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb
   50 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb
   51 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dependency.rb
   52 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/ruby_dsl.rb
   53 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dsl.rb
   54 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source.rb
   55 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb
   56 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb
   57 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ftp.rb
   58 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/http.rb
   59 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/https.rb
   60 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldap.rb
   61 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/ldaps.rb
   62 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/mailto.rb
   63 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri.rb
   64 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/socket.so
   65 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/socket.rb
   66 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb
   67 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/protocol.rb
   68 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/zlib.so
   69 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/stringio.so
   70 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/exceptions.rb
   71 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/header.rb
   72 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/generic_request.rb
   73 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/request.rb
   74 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/requests.rb
   75 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/response.rb
   76 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/responses.rb
   77 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/proxy_delta.rb
   78 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http/backward.rb
   79 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb
   80 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/date_core.so
   81 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date/format.rb
   82 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/date.rb
   83 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/time.rb
   84 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/request.rb
   85 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/core.rb
   86 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/util.rb
   87 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi/cookie.rb
   88 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/cgi.rb
   89 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/uri_formatter.rb
   90 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/fcntl.so
   91 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/openssl.so
   92 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/bn.rb
   93 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/cipher.rb
   94 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/config.rb
   95 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/digest.rb
   96 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/x509.rb
   97 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/buffering.rb
   98 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl/ssl.rb
   99 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/openssl.rb
  100 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/securerandom.rb
  101 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/fiddle.so
  102 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/function.rb
  103 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/closure.rb
  104 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle.rb
  105 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/value.rb
  106 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/pack.rb
  107 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/struct.rb
  108 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/cparser.rb
  109 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fiddle/import.rb
  110 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/registry.rb
  111 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/win32/resolv.rb
  112 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/resolv.rb
  113 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/remote_fetcher.rb
  114 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/text.rb
  115 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/name_tuple.rb
  116 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/spec_fetcher.rb
  117 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb
  118 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x64-mingw32/strscan.so
  119 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/path.rb
  120 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb
  121 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb
  122 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb
  123 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb
  124 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb
  125 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb
  126 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb
  127 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb
  128 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/index.rb
  129 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/remote_specification.rb
  130 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/endpoint_specification.rb
  131 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/dep_proxy.rb
  132 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb
  133 C:/Sites/simple_cms/config/boot.rb
  134 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/optparse.rb
  135 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.1.3/lib/thread_safe/version.rb
  136 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/delegate.rb
  137 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.1.3/lib/thread_safe/synchronized_delegator.rb
  138 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.1.3/lib/thread_safe.rb
  139 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/prepend_and_append.rb
  140 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/deep_merge.rb
  141 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb
  142 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb
  143 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/version.rb
  144 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/exceptions.rb
  145 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/interpolate/ruby.rb
  146 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n.rb
  147 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb
  148 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/config.rb
  149 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/i18n.rb
  150 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.1.3/lib/thread_safe/non_concurrent_cache_backend.rb
  151 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.1.3/lib/thread_safe/mri_cache_backend.rb
  152 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/thread_safe-0.1.3/lib/thread_safe/cache.rb
  153 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb
  154 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflections.rb
  155 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb
  156 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies/autoload.rb
  157 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/version.rb
  158 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/extract_options.rb
  159 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute_accessors.rb
  160 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/concern.rb
  161 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/logger_silence.rb
  162 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/logger.rb
  163 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/logger.rb
  164 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support.rb
  165 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb
  166 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/singleton_class.rb
  167 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/remove_method.rb
  168 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/attribute.rb
  169 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb
  170 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/singleton.rb
  171 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb
  172 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb
  173 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mutex_m.rb
  174 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications/fanout.rb
  175 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/per_thread_registry.rb
  176 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/notifications.rb
  177 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/behaviors.rb
  178 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb
  179 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/aliasing.rb
  ...
  452 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/delegating_attributes.rb
  453 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/reachable.rb
  454 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/class/subclasses.rb
  455 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/class.rb
  456 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.2/lib/action_mailer.rb
  457 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionmailer-4.0.2/lib/action_mailer/railtie.rb
  458 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/test_unit/railtie.rb
  459 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/version.rb
  460 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike.rb
  461 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb
  462 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/string.rb
  463 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/erb.rb
  464 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/etanni.rb
  465 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/haml.rb
  466 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/css.rb
  467 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/csv.rb
  468 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/coffee.rb
  469 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/nokogiri.rb
  470 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/builder.rb
  471 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markaby.rb
  472 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/liquid.rb
  473 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/radius.rb
  474 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/markdown.rb
  475 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/textile.rb
  476 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/rdoc.rb
  477 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/wiki.rb
  478 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/yajl.rb
  479 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/asciidoc.rb
  480 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/plain.rb
  481 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt.rb
  482 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/eco_template.rb
  483 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/ejs_template.rb
  484 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/jst_processor.rb
  485 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/utils.rb
  486 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/engines.rb
  487 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/mime.rb
  488 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/mime.rb
  489 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/processor.rb
  490 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/processing.rb
  491 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/compressing.rb
  492 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/paths.rb
  493 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/normalized_array.rb
  494 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/extensions.rb
  495 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/index.rb
  496 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/paths.rb
  497 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/hike-1.2.3/lib/hike/trail.rb
  498 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/shellwords.rb
  499 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/directive_processor.rb
  500 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/safety_colons.rb
  501 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/charset_normalizer.rb
  502 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/sass_compressor.rb
  503 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/yui_compressor.rb
  504 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/closure_compressor.rb
  505 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb
  506 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/sass_template.rb
  507 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets/scss_template.rb
  508 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.10.1/lib/sprockets.rb
  509 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/benchmarkable.rb
  510 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/active_model_helper.rb
  511 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb
  512 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb
  513 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb
  514 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_tag_helper.rb
  515 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/atom_feed_helper.rb
  516 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb
  517 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/controller_helper.rb
  518 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/csrf_helper.rb
  519 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb
  520 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/debug_helper.rb
  521 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/javascript_helper.rb
  522 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb
  523 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb
  524 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/filters.rb
  525 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/sanitize_helper.rb
  526 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/text_helper.rb
  527 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_tag_helper.rb
  528 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/tags.rb
  529 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/model_naming.rb
  530 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb
  531 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb
  532 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/number_helper.rb
  533 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb
  534 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/output_safety_helper.rb
  535 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/qualified_const.rb
  536 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/module.rb
  537 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/record_identifier.rb
  538 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/record_tag_helper.rb
  539 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb
  540 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers/translation_helper.rb
  541 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/actionpack-4.0.2/lib/action_view/helpers.rb
  542 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb
  543 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine/configuration.rb
  544 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb
  545 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/railtie.rb
  546 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/all.rb
  547 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/string_inquirer.rb
  548 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/version.rb
  549 C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/error.rb

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html


This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

C:\Sites\simple_cms>
```

I'm running Ruby 2.0.0-p353 (x64)
MySQL Server 5.6
Mysql2 0.3.14

all on Windows 8

Comment: I think it's better to work with Rails under Linux or Mac since most of developpers are working on these platforms. I also tried to install it on windows without any success. Anyway, this error can be caused by many things. Are you certain your MySQL server is running? And there is no typo in your database.yml?

Comment: possible duplicate of [...mysql2/mysql2.so: \[BUG\] Segmentation fault ruby 2.0.0p247](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160175/mysql2-mysql2-so-bug-segmentation-fault-ruby-2-0-0p247)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow the setup requirements for the mysql2 gem:

Taken from the [mysql2 gem GitHub](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2#windows):

> First, make sure you have the DevKit installed
>   (http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) and its variables are loaded by
>   running devkit\devktvars.bat .
>
> Next, you need a MySQL library to link against. If you have MySQL
>   loaded on your development machine, you can use that. If not, you will
>   need to either copy the MySQL directory from your server, or else
>   obtain a copy of the MySQL C connector:
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/
>
> If you're using the connector, I recommend just getting the .zip file
>   and unzipping it someplace convenient.
>
> Now you can install mysql2. You must use the --with-mysql-dir option
>   to tell gem where your MySQL library files are. For example, if you
>   unzipped the connector to c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32 you would
>   install the gem like this:
>
> gem install mysql2 --
>   --with-mysql-dir=c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32 Finally, you must copy libmysql.dll from the lib subdirectory of your MySQL or MySQL
>   connector directory into your ruby\bin directory. In the above
>   example, libmysql.dll would be located at
>   c:\mysql-connector-c-6.1.1-win32\lib .